# Regex words with hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex to match words (no spaces in them) that have at least one number, one letter (a-zA-Z), and at least one hyphen. And the total size should be between 4 and 40.

Examples:

hi how are you h9-11c **matches**  h9-11c

foo 79d-11c-afac bar **matches**  79d-11c-afac

foo d-c-afac bar **does not match**  - no number

I have come up with this so far:

```
\b(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*-).{4,40}\b
```

but it doesn't match just one word (it's a bit greedy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\S` to match non-whitespace characters.

Also, `\b` matches on boundaries of alphanumberic characters, but you have defined your words to be any non-whitespace.

```
(?<!\S)(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])(?=\S*-)\S{4,40}(?!\S)
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response... I'll select it as the answer when it lets me in a few minutes

Comment: Nice usage of the non-whitespace `\S` anchor, +1 for that.